# Why is it important to have schema or owner for a table when we can directly use the table itself

Tags: sql, schema, owner

I have seen various schema and tables under them.

What is the significance of using schema or owner name with Tables rather than tables only.

Comment: Then someone else (with select privilege) can use the same SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

schema definition is quite different in different database systems.

but generally schema is used to categorize & organize some interrelated database objects, such as tables, Stored procedures , etc.

here are some application/advantage of using schema:

- You can apply security permissions for separating and protecting database objects based on user access rights.
- A logical group of database objects can be managed within a database. Schemas play an important role in allowing the database objects to be organized into these logical groups.
- The schema also helps in situations where the database object name is the same. But these objects fall under different logical groups.
- The schema also helps in adding security.
- It helps in manipulating and accessing the objects which otherwise is a complex method.